# How to center a View in a panel

Tags: css, xpages

I've got a view control in a panel but can't seem to get the view control to center within the panel.  I've tried adding to the All Properties style "text-align:center;display:block;".   Any thoughts on how I can get this view centered?

thanks, 
clem

```
<xp:panel style="text-align:center;display:block;"
    id="presentationView">
    <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view2"
                viewName="PresentationStore">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="PresentationTitle"
            id="viewColumn1" displayAs="link" openDocAsReadonly="true" styleClass="footer">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:openPage name="/Comp_Presentation.xsp"
                        target="openDocument">
                    </xp:openPage>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>

</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<xp:panel>
    <xp:div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto">
        <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                    layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                </xp:pager>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="($All)"></xp:dominoView>
            </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="$106" id="viewColumn1">
                <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Date"
                    id="viewColumnHeader1">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:viewColumn>
        </xp:viewPanel>
        </xp:div>
</xp:panel>
```

Just replace the view data with your own code

Comment: I needed this again and forgot the trick.... The real secret here is this line:

     <xp:div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto">

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a DIV tag and center that DIV tag. I usually open my viewPanels at 80% so it expands to the browser window.